# Space between barbuttons

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem, uinavigationitem

I create 3 her bar button and want to assign it to right navigation item. I want to have space between then. I have very little space with my code, I tried to make in wider but not get it. My code

```
    UIBarButtonItem *actionBarButton = [UIBarButtonItem.alloc initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction target:self action:@selector(presentActivity)];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton;
UIBarButtonItem *prevBarButton = [UIBarButtonItem.alloc initWithImage:MHGalleryImage(@"left_arrow.png") style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(prevButtonAction:)];
UIBarButtonItem *nextBarButton = [UIBarButtonItem.alloc initWithImage:MHGalleryImage(@"right_arrow.png") style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(nextButtonAction:)];
UIBarButtonItem *flex = [UIBarButtonItem.alloc initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace target:self action:nil];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = @[actionBarButton, flex, flex, flex, flex, flex, flex, flex, flex, flex, flex, flex, flex, nextBarButton, flex, flex, flex, flex, flex, flex, prevBarButton, flex];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create space between buttons?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7633066/how-to-create-space-between-buttons)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explicitly define the `flex` bar button item's width like so:

```
UIBarButtonItem *flex = [UIBarButtonItem.alloc initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace
                                                                    target:nil
                                                                    action:nil];
NSLog(@"before -- %f",flex.width);
flex.width = 44;
NSLog(@"after -- %f",flex.width);

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = @[actionBarButton, flex, nextBarButton, flex, prevBarButton, flex];
```